# Passing image id to USEMAP OnClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, events

I am using usemap for set of images

```
<map name="movemap">
    <area shape="rect"  coords="0,0,200,200" a href="" onclick="jumps(); return false;">
</map>
```

I have a set of images which use the map. E.g.,

```
<img id=1 usemap=#movemap src=abc.gif />
<img id=2 usemap=#movemap src=def.gif />
<img id=3 usemap=#movemap src=xyz.gif />
```

Now within `jumps()` function I need to know which image was clicked. So in the `jumps()` onclick function, how can I get `id` of the image which was clicked by user.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to detect image by the map, you will either have to have 3 individual maps for the 3 images or, better yet, catch click event of images themselves instead of map

Comment: Depending on what you need, you can put a click listener in the `img` elements, get it's id (remember to never use number-only IDs - that's a bad pratice), and pass the ID as an argument to the `jump()` function. As I said, I don't know the scope of what you're in need of, so that's just a vague suggestion. :)